# Why is this a topology?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $ Q \subset P(X), \ Q \not= \emptyset$ and define $B_Q = \{B : B = \cap_{j=1}^{n} E_j, E_j \in Q \}$. Now let 
>   $T_Q = \{ A: A = \cup_{i \in I}\  B_i, B_i \in B_Q \} $. Then $T_Q$ is a topology on $X$.

Why is this a topology on $X$, I don't "see" how one can be certain that $T_Q$ contains $X, \emptyset$. Perhaps if someone can explain why it is that $T,\emptyset \in T_Q$. Then I can figure out the rest.

Comment: It seems that you must write $E_j\subset Q$ instead of $E_j \in Q$. Edit your post before some psychopath put you a downvote.

Comment: $B_Q$ is meant to be the set containing finite intersections of sets in $Q$. One of them is the empty intersection ($n=0$ is allowed) which is identified with $X$. Likewise the empty set is the empty union and belongs to $T_Q$ ($I=\varnothing$ is allowed).

Comment: Note that $x\in\cap\varnothing$ iff $x\in A$ for every $A\in\varnothing$. This is vacuously true, and this for every $x\in X$. So $X\subseteq\cap\varnothing$. Working in "universe" X by convention $\cap\varnothing\subseteq X$. This explains why $\cap\varnothing$ is identified with $X$ in this context.

Comment: Even though that was hard to understand for me, it made it clearer. That is the part that I missed. @drhab

Comment: @Olba12 Glad to hear things are more clear now.

Comment: @Piquito did $E_j\in Q$ not make sense? $Q\subset P(X)$ meant $Q$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, so $E_j\in Q$ means $E_j\subset X$.

Comment: Final remark: your definitions of $B_Q$ and $T_Q$ are not properly stated. They contain some free $n$ and some free $I$ respectively, which is not allowed. Actually $B_Q:=\{\cap C\mid C\subseteq Q\wedge C\text{ is finite}\}$ and $T_Q:=\{\cup D\mid D\subseteq B_Q\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a point of carelessness that seems to occur rather often: quite often one needs to add words like "oh, yeah, I forgot to say that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are elements of the topology". I have been guilty of this in the topology class that I teach.

But in this case, there is a set theoretic formality that might let the writer of this problem off the hook. $B_Q$ is defined as the set of intersections of arbitrary finite subsets of $Q$; one could say that $X$ is the intersection of the empty subset of $Q$. Similarly, $T_Q$ is defined to be the set of unions of arbitrary subsets of $B_Q$; one could say that $\emptyset$ is the union of the empty subset of $B_Q$.

Comment: "one could say that $X$ is the intersection of the empty subset of $Q$", I read that sentence as $X = \cap \emptyset\in Q$ which makes no sense to me. So can you please explain it further?

Comment: @Olba12 you should read that sentence as: $X=\cap\varnothing\in B_Q$